# How can I pass dynamic limit to the ORM instance in Phalcon?

Tags: php, datatables, phalcon

Here is my phalcon controller Action in this function i m using `phalcon-datatable`

my query is i want to pass dynamic limit argument to this model `$jangads::ViewJangads()`  Currently I m Passing static limit `"limit=>100"` i want it as a dynamic that response to server side processing

```
    public function phalconDatatableLoadAction() {
        if ($this->request->isAjax()) {
            $this->setJsonResponse();
            $request = $this->request;
            if (!$request->isPost()) {
                $this->invalid_request = true;
                return;
            }
            $type = $request->getPost("id_type");
            $from_date = $request->getPost("from_date");
            $to_date = $request->getPost("to_date");
            $from_carat = $request->getPost("from_carat");
            $to_carat = $request->getpost("to_carat");
            $machine_id = $request->getpost("machine_id");
            $process_id = $request->getPost("process_id");
            $client_id = $request->getPost("client_id");
            $payment_type = $request->getPost("payment_type");
            $condition = "";
            if ($from_carat === NULL && $to_carat === NULL && $from_date === NULL && $to_date = NULL && $machine_id === NULL && $process_id === NULL && $client_id === NULL) {
                $this->invalid_request = true;
                $jangads = ViewJangads::find(array("limit"=>100, "order" => "id DESC"));  //Here I want to Pass Dynamic Limit in array
                return array('jangads' => $jangads);
            }
            if ($from_date != NULL && $to_date != NULL) {
                $condition = "date_in BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'";
            }
            if ($type != NULL) {
                if ($condition != NULL) {
                    $condition = " and " . $condition;
                }
                $condition = "type='$type'" . $condition;
            }
            if ($from_carat != NULL && $to_carat != NULL) {
                if ($condition != NULL) {
                    $condition = " and " . $condition;
                }
                $condition = "total_weight BETWEEN '$from_carat' and '$to_carat'" . $condition;
            }
            if ($client_id != NULL) {
                if ($condition != NULL) {
                    $condition = " and " . $condition;
                }
                $condition = "client_id='$client_id'" . $condition;
            }
            if ($machine_id != NULL) {
                if ($condition != NULL) {
                    $condition = " and " . $condition;
                }
                $condition = "find_in_set('$machine_id',machine_id)<>0" . $condition;
            }
            if ($process_id != NULL) {
                if ($condition != NULL) {
                    $condition = " and " . $condition;
                }
                $condition = "find_in_set('$process_id',process_id)<>0" . $condition;
            }
            if ($payment_type != NULL) {
                if ($condition != NULL) {
                    $condition = " and " . $condition;
                }
                $condition = "payment_type='$payment_type'" . $condition;
            }
            //$condition = "net_weight BETWEEN '$from_carat' and '$to_weight' and id_party='$id_party' and id_machine='$id_machine' ";

            $jangads = ViewJangads ::find(array("conditions" => $condition, "limit"=>100, "order" => "id DESC"));  //Here Also I want to pass dynamic limit
            $dataTables = new DataTable();
            $dataTables->fromResultSet($jangads)->sendResponse();
            return array('jangads' => $jangads, 'condition' => $condition);
        }
    }
```

if I'm not include limit argument in model then it show `mysql` memory issue bcz i have large database and i don't want to increase memory size so help needed 
and I'm using phalcon framework

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your dynamic limit coming from? You can include it in your Ajax request and assign it to $limit as you did with your other variables:

```
$limit = (int) $request->getPost("limit");
```

and use it like:

```
 "limit"=> $limit
```

If your datasets are so big, you can use a mix of LIMIT and OFFSET.

You might also like to explore this feature of Phalcon regarding resultsets:

> As storing large query results in memory could consume many resources, resultsets are obtained from the database in chunks of 32 rows - reducing the need to re-execute the request in several cases. (From the [docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.3/db-models#resultsets))